# How can I create cumulative string concatenation across rows with ordering of the string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to add a column to my database which performs row-wise cumulative concatenations of the values of another column for each ID, and orders the resulting string by a different hierarchy. The dataset is very large and the result I designed an smaller test data isn't workable on a larger scale so I need help redesigning it.

I have written the query so far using a combination of a recursive CTE to perform the cumulative concatenation (step 1 output below), and then a slightly clunky function (step 2 output below) to order the strings according to a separate hierarchy which also removes the '1' value. These work on a small subset of my data (n=60), but when I try to run an a larger subset (n=500,000) the CTE table runs forever (stopped without completing at 2hours). The real dataset will be in an order of magnitude of hundred of millions of rows, so solution isn't workable for that scale.

```
ID  Start_Date  End_Date    Seg step1       step2
1   01/04/1946  31/12/1990  1   1            1
1   01/01/1991  08/01/2007  4   4            4
1   09/01/2007  04/02/2007  1   1            1
1   05/02/2007  18/10/2017  4   14           4
1   01/04/2013  18/10/2017  8   148          48
1   11/11/2014  18/10/2017  7   1487         487
2   01/05/1931  31/12/1997  1   1            1
2   01/01/1998  20/01/2014  4   4            4
2   31/01/2011  20/01/2014  6   146          46
2   21/02/2013  20/01/2014  5   1465         456
2   01/04/2013  20/01/2014  8   14658        4586
2   29/04/2013  20/01/2014  7   146587       45876
```

There are additional complicated logic elements, such as only starting the cumulation when the start date is earlier than the previous row end date, so a solution which allows flexibility by adding `where` or `case when` statements is key.

Example of the recursive CTE and ordering function I have used (not adapted for the simplified table shown, but indicative of the structure I have used) are below.

Recursive CTE (output step 1 column)

```
with t (ID, Segment,start_date, start_comb,updated_end_date ,rn) as (
            select ID, Segment, start_date, case when Segment_end_date <> resolved_date OR Segment_end_date is null then 1 else 0 end as start_comb
                                                    ,updated_end_date
                                                    ,row_number() over (partition by ID order by start_date) as rn
                                                    from #test_IDs
) 

,r (ID, orig_seg, Segment, rn, start_comb, start_date, updated_end_date) as (

  select ID, cast(Segment as varchar(max)), cast(Segment as varchar(max)),rn, start_comb, start_date, updated_end_date
  from t
  where start_comb=0
  union all
  select r.ID, cast(t.segment as varchar(max)) as orig_seg
  , Segment = cast( (concat(r.Segment,t.Segment)) as varchar(max))
  , t.rn, t.start_comb, t.start_date, t.updated_end_date
  from r
  join t on t.ID = r.ID and t.rn = r.rn + 1 and t.start_comb <> 0 
)
```

Ordering function (output step 2 column)

```
if object_id ('reformat') is not null
drop function reformat

create function dbo.reformat
( 
    @unordered_Segs varchar(max)
)
returns varchar(255)
as
begin

    declare @healthy int, @first int, @second int, @third int, @fourth int, @fifth int, @outtext int

    if Charindex('4',@unordered_segs)  > 0 

            set @first = 4
            else set @first = ''
    if Charindex('5',@unordered_segs)  > 0

            set @second = 5
            else set @second = ''
    if Charindex('8',@unordered_segs)  > 0

            set @third = 8
            else set @third = ''
    if Charindex('7',@unordered_segs)  > 0

            set @fourth = 7
            else set @fourth = ''
    if Charindex('6',@unordered_segs)  > 0

            set @fifth = 6
            else set @fifth = ''

    if Charindex('1',@unordered_segs)  > 0 and len(@unordered_segs) = 1
            set @outtext = 1
            else
    set @outtext = Replace((concat(@first,@second,@third,@fourth,@fifth)),'0','')

return      @outtext
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Someone is probably going to request sample desired output for your sample set.

Comment: Scalar valued functions have awful performance; combining that with a recursive CTE is a recipe for disaster. The function can be rewritten as an inline table-valued function (using `CASE`); that alone should bring significant improvements. If your data set gets sufficiently large it may be worth thinking about a custom CLR aggregate; setting this up has a learning curve but it may beat T-SQL's anemic string handling. Also, while I'm not fully clear on your use case, consider if `hierarchyid` can be proficiently used here somewhere (possibly with an extra processing pass).

Comment: So for clarity, the final output column is the 'step 2' column in the table above which has cumulatively concatenated the values in the 'Seg' column over the ID field, and orders these values in a specific hierarchy not related to the order in which they are aggregated.

Comment: Also regarding the function, its actually just the CTE which is causing huge problems - I haven't heard of CLR aggregation so will have a look!